# Open Type Level Proofs in Haskell/Idris

Tags: haskell, proof, category-theory, correctness, idris

In Idris/Haskell, one can prove properties of data by annotating the types and using GADT constructors, such as with Vect, however, this requires hardcoding the property into the type (e.g. a Vect has to be a separate type from a List).
Is it possible to have types with an open set of properties (such as list carrying both a length and running average), for example by overloading constructors or using something in the vein of Effect?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe that McBride has answered that question (for Type Theory) in his [ornament paper (pdf)](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/OAAO/Ornament.pdf). The concept you are looking for is the one of an algebraic ornament (emphasis mine):

> An algebra φ describes a structural method to interpret data, giving
>   rise to a fold φ oper- ation, applying the method recursively.
>   Unsurprisingly, the resulting tree of calls to φ has the same
>   structure as the original data — that is the point, after all. But
>   what if that were, before all, the point? Suppose we wanted to fix the
>   result of fold φ in advance, representing only those data which would
>   deliver the answer we wanted. We should need the data to fit with a
>   tree of φ calls which delivers that answer. **Can we restrict our data
>   to exactly that? Of course we can, if we index by the answer.**

Now, let's write some code. I've put the whole thing [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/gallais/e507832abc6c91ac7cb9) because I'm going to interleave comments in here. Also, I'm using Agda but it should be easy to tranlate to Idris.

```
module reornament where
```

We start by defining what it means to be an algebra delivering `B`s acting on a list of `A`s. We need a base case (a value of type `B`) as well as way to combine the head of the list with the induction hypothesis.

```
ListAlg : (A B : Set) → Set
ListAlg A B = B × (A → B → B)
```

Given this definition, we can define a type of lists of `A`s indexed by `B`s whose value is precisely the result of the computation corresponding to a given `ListAlg A B`. In the `nil` case, the result is the base case provided to us by the algebra (`proj₁ alg`) whilst in the `cons` case, we simply combine the induction hypothesis with the new head using the second projection:

```
data ListSpec (A : Set) {B : Set} (alg : ListAlg A B) : (b : B) → Set where
  nil  :  ListSpec A alg (proj₁ alg)
  cons : (a : A) {b : B} (as : ListSpec A alg b) → ListSpec A alg (proj₂ alg a b)
```

Ok, let's import some libraries and see a couple of examples now:

```
open import Data.Product
open import Data.Nat
open import Data.List
```

The algebra computing the length of a list is given by `0` as the base case and `const suc` as the way to combine an `A` and the length of the tail to build the length of the current list. Hence:

```
AlgLength : {A : Set} → ListAlg A ℕ
AlgLength = 0 , (λ _ → suc)
```

If the elements are natural numbers then they can be summed. The algebra corresponding to that has `0` as the base case and `_+_` as the way to combine an `ℕ` together with the sum of the elements contained in the tail. Hence:

```
AlgSum : ListAlg ℕ ℕ
AlgSum = 0 , _+_
```

Crazy thought: If we have two algebras working on the same elements, we can combine them! This way we'll track 2 invariants rather than one!

```
Alg× : {A B C : Set} (algB : ListAlg A B) (algC : ListAlg A C) →
       ListAlg A (B × C)
Alg× (b , sucB) (c , sucC) = (b , c) , (λ a → λ { (b , c) → sucB a b , sucC a c })
```

An now the examples:

If we are tracking the length, then we can define Vectors:

```
Vec : (A : Set) (n : ℕ) → Set
Vec A n = ListSpec A AlgLength n
```

And have, e.g., this vector of length 4:

```
allFin4 : Vec ℕ 4
allFin4 = cons 0 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil)))
```

If we are tracking the sum of the elements, then we can define a notion of distribution: a statistical distribution is a list of probabilities whose sum is 100:

```
Distribution : Set
Distribution = ListSpec ℕ AlgSum 100
```

And we can define a uniform one for instance:

```
uniform : Distribution
uniform = cons 25 (cons 25 (cons 25 (cons 25 nil)))
```

Finally, by combining the length and sum algebras, we can implement the notion of sized distribution.

```
SizedDistribution : ℕ → Set
SizedDistribution n = ListSpec ℕ (Alg× AlgLength AlgSum) (n , 100)
```

And give this nice uniform distribution for a 4 elements set:

```
uniform4 : SizedDistribution 4
uniform4 = cons 25 (cons 25 (cons 25 (cons 25 nil)))
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I wrote an Idris translation: https://gist.github.com/puffnfresh/35213f97ec189757a179

Comment: @BrianMcKenna Amazing, indeed. Is it possible to express heterogenous list as such ornamentation? Or increasing list?

Comment: @SamuraiJack Sure. You need to come up with a type of objects to store in the list and the corresponding `fold` computing the invariant from the list of elements. Here's what I got: https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/2d346c10ece927dc9cfa7fab8e7d7c41f37cac7e/agda/poc/ListSpec.agda

Comment: @gallais looks cool, thanks! 
BrianMcKenna Any chances of Idris translation? :)