# Can I have an unknown KnownNat?

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

I wonder if I can have my cake and eat it too regarding `KnownNats`. Can I write code that uses `Nats` that may be both `KnownNats` and `UnknownNats` (`SomeNats`?).

For example if I have a dependently typed vector `Vec (n :: Nat) a`, can I write code that works both if the size is known at compile and at runtime? Thing is that I don't want to duplicate the whole code for statically and dynamically sized "things". And I don't want to lose static guarantees by storing sizes in the data structure.

#### Edit

Answer to András Kovács:

My specific usecase is reading images from disk (which are luckily of fixed size) and then extracting patches from that, so basically I have a function `extractPatch :: (KnownNat w2, KnownNat h2) => Image w1 h1 a -> Patch w2 h2` a where both `Image` and `Patch` are instances of a common `Mat (w :: Nat) (h :: Nat)` a type.

If I wouldn't know the image size I would have to encode this in "runtime types". Just wondering.

Comment: Pretty much any code one might write with `Nat`-s should work equally with statically known and unknown values. Is there something specific you'd like to do, but don't know how to implement?

Comment: You can define `Vec` as `Vec (n :: Maybe Nat) a`, but I wouldn't do such a thing in Haskell. One another option is to [check your invariants](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27070207/3237465). Or you can use [ornaments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27220545/3237465).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's something potentially interesting...

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy

data Bar (n :: Nat) = Bar String deriving Show

bar :: KnownNat n => Bar n -> (String, Integer)
bar b@(Bar s) = (s, natVal b)
```

Ok, it's very pointless.  But it's an example of using `KnownNat` to get at compile-time information.  But thanks to the other functions in `GHC.TypeLits`, it can be used with run-time information as well.

Just add this on to the above code, and try it out.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    i <- readLn
    let Just someNat = someNatVal i
    case someNat of
       SomeNat (_ :: Proxy n) -> do
           let b :: Bar n
               b = Bar "hello!"
           print $ bar b
```

Let's break down what happens here.

1. Read an `Integer` from stdin.
2. Create a `SomeNat`-typed value from it, failing the pattern-match if the input was negative. For such a simple example, handling that error just gets in the way.
3. Here's the real magic.  Pattern-match with a `case` expression, using `ScopedTypeVariables` to bind the (statically unknown) `Nat`-kinded type to the type variable `n`.
4. Finally, create a `Bar` value with that particular `n` as its type variable and then do things with it.

Comment: Thanks that was informative. To be honest I don't know if I can apply it if the need comes up (see edit above), but the concept seems clear.