# Type safe modular arthmetic no annotation

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming, dependent-type, modular-arithmetic

There's a number of Haskell modular arithmetic modules that implement type safe modular arithmetic with type annotations. Is it possible to pass in a *variable* in the type annotation?

For example in the *mod* module the following works

```
let x = 4 :: Mod 7
let y = 5 :: Mod 7
print x + y
```

Is there any way to achieve something similar to the following

```
let base = 7
let x = 4 :: Mod base
let y = 5 :: Mod base
print x + y
```

My problem here is that `base` is not a type. I'm unsure of the correct way to approach this problem or whether I'm thinking about this in the wrong way for functional languages. Thanks.

**Update**

In practice base will be the result of some computation I do not know in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? For the specific example you gave, you don’t need to define a separate `base`, since `base` is just a constant in your example.

Comment: You're not thinking about this the wrong way for functional languages _in general_; only for Haskell in particular. You're looking for "dependent types", which are a very natural way of thinking about and expressing many mathematical things, and which some functional languages _do_ support. Take a look at languages like Agda and Lean if you're interested. The catch (and it's a big one) is that in the presence of dependent types, type checking can become undecidable, requiring the developer to provide proofs to aid the type checker.

Comment: See also https://wiki.haskell.org/Dependent_type

Comment: @bradrn In practice base will be the output of another function, for example the size of an external file. I was trying to give a minimal example in this case, maybe too minimal...

Comment: @notmeduo If `base` is generated by the program, then you’ll want to use [`someNatVal :: Natural -> SomeNat`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeNats.html#v:someNatVal) to convert your value into a type-level natural. That will then let you create and manipulate a `Mod` with the generated base, albeit under an existential — you’ll probably need to define some variant of `newtype SomeMod = forall b. SomeMod (Mod b)`. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) @notmeduo Also, if you want to do any more complex manipulation than that, you may also want to look into the [`singletons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question

[Can I have an unknown KnownNat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752653/can-i-have-an-unknown-knownnat)

this can be applied in the given example as

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
module Main where

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Mod as M

f x = x + 2

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let y = f 5
    let Just someNat = someNatVal y
    case someNat of
        SomeNat (_ :: Proxy n) -> do
            let x = 4 :: M.Mod n
            let y = 5 :: M.Mod n
            print $ x + y
```

Answer (score 1):

A value parameterized by the `base` is a polymorphic value:

```hs
import Data.Mod
import GHC.TypeNats (Nat)

nine :: KnownNat base => Mod base
nine =
  let x = 4
      y = 5
  in x + y   -- Let type inference do the work of deducing that x, y :: Mod base
```

To explicitly annotate these expressions, use `ScopedTypeVariables` to be able to refer to the `base` type variable. This also requires `base` to be explicitly quantified:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.Mod
import GHC.TypeNats (Nat)

nine :: forall base. KnownNat base => Mod base
nine =
  let x = 4 :: Mod base
      y = 5 :: Mod base
  in x + y
```

Comment: I’m not sure how this answers the question. As indicated in the comments, OP seems to want to generate the `base` value at run-time and then lift it to the type level. Certainly I’m sure `-XScopedTypeVariables` will be used _somewhere_ in that process, but in and of itself I don’t think this makes up a full answer.

Comment: @bradm That's some pretty harsh feedback. I'm providing a partial answer (which technically answers the original post BTW) in the hope that it will help OP refine their question. I'll be happy to clarify further based on that.

Comment: I hope my edit didn't change the question's meaning in any way, that certainly wasn't my intention.

Comment: Sorry @Li-yaoXia — I didn’t mean to be harsh, so sorry if my comment ended up sounding that way! I simply wanted to say that I was a bit confused by this answer, but I think my comment ended up sounding more harsher than I intended. (I posted it very late at night in my timezone — I probably shouldn’t do that! But thanks for the reply; now that I’m aware of it, I do see now how this could be a partial answer in the hope it helps OP at least a bit.