# Type family constraints at runtime // Couldn't match type `1 <=? n0' with 'True

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation

StackOverflow!

For reasons that would like to remain between me and God, I'm currently playing around with promoting runtime naturals to the type level. I've been following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30762622/1953518) with GHC.TypeLits, which has worked out fine so far.

However, in one instance, I have an additional constraint of `1 <= n`, i.e. my promoted natural not to be just any natural, but at least 1. This is also from [GHC.TypeLits](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#g:3) And I am unsure if/how it is possible to extract and make that information known.

Here's a minimal non-working example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits
import Numeric.Natural

data AnyNat (n :: Nat) where
  AN :: AnyNat n

data AtLeast1Nat (n :: Nat) where
  AL1N :: AtLeast1Nat n

promote0 :: Natural -> AnyNat n
promote0 k = case sn of
  SomeNat (_ :: Proxy p) -> AN 
  where
    sn = (fromJust . someNatVal . toInteger) k

promote1 :: (KnownNat n, 1 <= n) => Natural -> AtLeast1Nat n
promote1 k = case sn of
  SomeNat (_ :: Proxy p) -> AL1N 
  where
    sn = (fromJust . someNatVal . toInteger) k

main :: IO ()
main = do nat_in <- getLine
          let nat = read nat_in :: Natural
          let p0  = promote0 nat
          let p1  = promote1 nat
          putStrLn "Last statement must be an expression"
```

This produces this error (full error [here](https://pastebin.com/GYuwWEEb), but this is the relevant part):

```
    * Couldn't match type `1 <=? n0' with 'True
        arising from a use of `promote1'
      The type variable `n0' is ambiguous
```

Honestly, this isn't too surprising and I (think I) do understand *why* this happens. The `Natural` that we give in *could* be any of them, so why would we be able to derive that `1 <= n`? That's why it works fine for `promote0` and not `promote1`.

**My question** is hence, is there any way to also check (and propagate to type-level) this information so I can use it as intended, or am I using the wrong approach here?

Comment: You're not “promoting runtime naturals to the type level” here, that isn't even possible in Haskell. (Note that e.g. `promote0 3 :: AnyNat 4` happily typechecks.)

Comment: What am I doing, then?

Comment: `promote0 n :: AnyNat 4` is basically an _assertion_ that `n` must be `4` at runtime, or else crash the program.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Do you know if there's a way to match the `1 <= n` constraint with one of these assertions, somehow?

Comment: To what avail, though? That doesn't make sense, as the question stands. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I kept the details out of the initial example because I didn't think they'd matter. But ultimately, I want the user to enter a number and have a Sized.Vector value that has that size. Would have been nice if you could've done it with one value that's "polymorphic" for all n >= 1, but I'll look for another way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong approach.

As discussed in the comments, `promote0` (and similarly `promote1`) isn't doing what you're hoping.  The problem is that the `AN` on the right-hand-side of the case has type `AnyNat n` for some `n` entirely unrelated to the term `sn`.  You could have written:

```
promote0 k = case 2+2 of 4 -> AN
```

and gotten much the same effect.  Note the critical difference between your code and the other Stack Overflow answer you link:  in that answer, the type variable `n` in the case scrutinee is used to type something (via `ScopedTypeVariables`) in the case branch.  You bind a type variable `p` in your scrutinee but then don't use it for anything.

If we consider your actual problem, suppose we want to write something like this:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Sized as V

main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  let Just v  = V.fromList (replicate n 1)
      v2 = v V.++ v
  print $ v2
```

This won't type check.  It gives an error on `V.fromList` about the lack of a `KnownNat` constraint.  The issue is that `v` has been assigned a type `S.Vector k Int` for some `k :: Nat`.  But `V.fromList` performs a runtime check that the length of the input list (the run time value `n`) is equal to the type-level `k`.  To do this, `k` must be converted to a runtime integer which requires `KnownNat k`.

The general solution, as you've guessed, is to construct a `SomeNat` that basically contains a `KnownNat n => n` that's unknown at compile time.   However, you don't want to try to promote it to a known type-level `Nat` (i.e., you don't want `promote0`).  You want to leave it as-is and `case` match on it at the point you need its type-level value.  That type-level value will be available within the `case` but unavailable outside the `case`, so no types that depend on `n` can "escape" the case statement.

So, for example, you can write:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Sized as V
import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeNats

main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  -- keep `sn` as the type-level representation of the runtime `n`
  let sn = someNatVal (fromIntegral n)
  -- scrutinize it when you need its value at type level
  case sn of
    -- bind the contained Nat to the type variable `n`
    SomeNat (Proxy :: Proxy n) -> do
      -- now it's available at the type level
      let v  = V.replicate @n 1   -- using type-level "n"
          v2 = v V.++ v
      print v2
```

but you can't write:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  n <- readLn :: IO Int
  let sn = someNatVal (fromIntegral n)
  let v2 = case sn of
        SomeNat (Proxy :: Proxy n) ->
          let v  = V.replicate @n 1
          in  v V.++ v
  print v2
```

You'll get an error that a type variable is escaping its scope.  (If you want to let sized vectors leak outside the `case`, you need to make use of `V.SomeSized` or something similar.)

As for the main part of your question about handling a `1 <= n` constraint, dealing with inequalities for type-level naturals is a major headache.  I think you'll need to post a minimal example of exactly how you want to use this constraint in the context of a sized vector imlementation, in order to get a decent answer.

Comment: Thank you, that clears a few things up. I'll post another workup with a complete example sometime.